# Functions without arguments, with unit as argument in scala

Tags: scala

```
def foo(x: Int, f: Unit => Int) = println(f())

foo(2, { Unit => 3 + 4 })

// case 1
def loop: Int = 7
foo(2, loop) // does not compile

changing loop to 
// case 2
def loop(): Int = 7
foo(2, loop) // does not compile

changing loop to
// case 3
def loop(x: Unit): Int = 7 // changing according to Don's Comments
foo(2, loop) // compiles and works fine
```

Shouldn't `case 1` and `case 2` also work? Why are they not working?

Defining foo as

```
def foo(x: Int, y: () => Int)
```

then `case 2` works but not `case 1`.

Arent they all supposed to work, defining the functions either way?

Also I think `() => Int` in foo is a bad style, `y:=> Int` does not work. Comments?

Comment: def defines methods (which are not first class), not functions (which *are* first class). Partial application lifts methods to functions when you need them.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.. I didnt get it. Did you mean, that the def's cannot be passed around. i.e the "loop" above cannot be passed to other functions?

Comment: Correct. When we say "first class" we mean of the same status as any other value like an Int, a String or an instance of some user-defined class. Methods cannot be treated in this way (they can only be called). Functions, on the other hand (which are instances of (subclasses of) FunctionN (N being the number of arguments)), are first class entities for the obvious reason that they're instances of a class.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Scala distinguishes between the following things:

- Functions/methods with *no parameter lists* ("by-name parameter" if a function)
- Functions with *one empty parameter list*
- Functions with *one parameter of type Unit*

None of these are equivalent, although as a convenience Scala allows you to elide empty parameter lists.  (Incidentally, two empty parameter lists are also not the same.)

So, even though `Unit` is written `()`, this is *not* the same as the function argument parens `()` for a function or method.  Instead, think of `()` as a `Tuple0`.

So, if you say `f: Unit => Int`, what you mean is "f takes one parameter, but it's a really boring parameter because it is `Unit`, which must always be the same boring `Tuple0` value `()`".  What you're writing is really short for `f: (Unit) => Int`.

If you say `f: () => Int`, then you mean that "f takes no parameters and produces an `Int`".

If you say `f: => Int`, then you mean that "delay the execution of whatever statement produces an `Int` value until we use it in this code (and re-evaluate it each time)".  Functionally, this ends up being basically the same as `f: () => Int` (and internally is converted into the same `Function0` class), but it has a different usage, presumably to allow for a more compact form of closures (you always omit the `=>` in the calling code).

Comment: So if I have a function def loop() = 7
It really makes no sense for me to insert unit, as in
def loop(x:Unit) = 7 , if I want to pass it to another function like foo above.

Comment: @Scout: There's no reason to add a superfluous `Unit` in that case.  It is useful for abstraction.  Suppose you have a composition function: `def comp[A,B,C](f: A=>B, g: B=>C, a: A) = g(f(a))` and you try to pass it a `f` that doesn't return a value.  Now what do you do?  Well, it turns out that Scala always _does_ return something--at least `()` (the only possible value of type `Unit`).  So now you can write a `g` that takes an input of type `Unit` and use the general composition function above.  But for most situations, just use `def f() = ...` or `def f = ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was trying to figure out how to do lazy evaulation. Note that the space between the `:` and `=` in `f: => Int` is important.

Comment: @Jus12 - Indeed.  Space between all operator characters is important.  For example, `val x=-2` is not going to work, because although you are probably thinking `x` equals `-2`, the parser sees `x`, weird operator `=-`, and `2`.  `:` is the 
"declare my type" operator; `=>` is the "function produces this" operator.

Comment: Isn't it wrong to say () and Unit are the same? I would have thought () is the only INSTANCE of TYPE Unit. Just like null is the only instance of type Null?

Comment: The existence of both "f: () => Int" and "f: => Int" makes it too ambiguous, even scalac looks confused. If I use "f: () => Int" in an implicit function, it doesn't compile at any case

Comment: @Rex Kerr - sorry, I am confused by your example of composition. `g:B=>C` means `g` needs input `B`. Then how could I pass an `f` that doesn't return `B`? I am struggling to understand why compiler differentiates between `Unit` and `()`  as far as function arguments are concerned.

Comment: Thank you for that paragraph explaining `f: => Int`. It took me way to long to find that `Seq.fill(n: Int)(elem: => Int)` re-evaluates `elem` for each index. All the online tutorials seem to indicate that `Seq.fill` replicates the _same_ element, but this is not the case.

Answer (score 15):

()=>Int is Function0[Int] while Unit=>Int is Function1[Unit,Int]

```
scala> val function0: () => Int = () => 5
function0: () => Int = <function0>

scala> val function1: Unit => Int = u => 5
function1: (Unit) => Int = <function1>

scala> function0()
res0: Int = 5

scala> function1("anything")
res1: Int = 5

scala> function1(100)
res2: Int = 5

scala>
```

Also note that () is an object of Unit

```
scala> function1(())
res11: Int = 5

scala> function1 ()
res12: Int = 5

scala> function1()
res13: Int = 5

scala> val unit = ()
unit: Unit = ()


scala> function1(unit)
res15: Int = 5

scala> function1 apply unit
res16: Int = 5

scala>
```

Comment: scala> val function1: Unit => Int = Unit => 5

Note that in this line, the last "Unit" is not a type identifier, but just a name for the parameter (you could change it to "x" for example).

Comment: I get why `function1(())` and `function1 ()` works, but I don't understand why `function1()` works.  I would expect this to follow the typical method invocation rules in Scala, that is, you'd need the space after the function name, or the unit value between the parameter parens...

Answer (score 2):

In case 1 and 2 above, the return value of **loop** rather than **loop** itself is type checked for the second argument to **foo** and fails: **Int != Unit => Int**

The change to **loop** has a typo.