# What is the FunctionN trait that represents a function taking a by-name parameter?

Tags: scala

A function in Scala is an object that implements one of the `FunctionN` traits. For example:

```
scala> def f(x: Int) = x * x
f: (x: Int)Int

scala> val ff = f _
ff: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val fff: Function1[Int, Int] = f _
fff: Int => Int = <function1>
```

So far, so good. But what if we have a function that takes a by-name parameter? It certainly does still implement one of the  `FunctionN` traits:

```
scala> def g(x: => Int) = x * x
g: (x: => Int)Int

scala> val gg = g _
gg: => Int => Int = <function1>

scala> gg.isInstanceOf[Function1[_, _]]
res0: Boolean = true
```

But what type is it, exactly? It's not `Function1[Int, Int]`:

```
scala> val ggg: Function1[Int, Int] = g _
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : => Int => Int
 required: Int => Int
       val ggg: Function1[Int, Int] = g _
                                      ^
```

Nor is it `Function1[Function0[Int], Int]`:

```
scala> val ggg: Function1[Function0[Int], Int] = g _
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : => Int => Int
 required: () => Int => Int
       val ggg: Function1[Function0[Int], Int] = g _
                                                 ^
```

And `Function1[=> Int, Int]` fails to compile:

```
scala> val ggg: Function1[=> Int, Int] = g _
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '=>' found.
       val ggg: Function1[=> Int, Int] = g _
                          ^
```

So what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**By-name is very useful but unsafe outside the type system**

Scala by-name parameters are a syntactic sugar to make code more readable when lazy evaluation is needed. Without it we would need to put "() =>" in front of everything that needed to be lazy. That said, while it is just a function0 at runtime, it would be problematic at the typing system level if you could define anything other than a parameter as having a by-name type. Also remember that the FunctionN traits are there mostly for implementation and Java interoperability since there is no such thing as a function type in Java and the JVM.

**Being explicit**

If you do need to be explicit in your typing the following will allow you to be restrictive

```
def g(x: => Int) = x * x
val ggg: (=> Int) => Int = g _
```

**More complex typing**

The by-name typing can only be used inside the parameter portion of function type declarations. The function types themselves can then be used inside other parametrized types.

```
var funks: List[(=> Int) => Int] = Nil
funks ::= ggg
funks foreach { _ { println("hi"); 5 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rex Kerr's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774516/functions-without-arguments-with-unit-as-argument-in-scala) gives you a hint: The by-name argument is eventually converted to a `Function0`, but probably treated specially at compile-time.

You can verify this:

```
scala> gg(sys.error("me"))
java.lang.RuntimeException: me
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:10)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:10)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcI$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcI$sp
    ...
```

**EDIT**

To extend on my first comment, this also indicates that you cannot give a *type* for a by-name parameter:

```
def test[A: Manifest](fun: Function1[A, Int]): Unit =
  println("Found " + implicitly[Manifest[A]])

scala> test(gg)
<console>:11: error: No Manifest available for => Int.
              test(gg)
                  ^
```

Comment: Sure - I have no doubt that that's what's happening under the hood. But if I want to specify the type of the function instead of allowing it to be inferred, what is it, exactly? Surely it can't be the case that I can create something where I can't write out its type? Can it?!

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. That is to say, that there is actually a 'type' corresponding to a by-name argument. E.g. `gg.getClass.getMethods.find(_.getName=="apply").get` yields also an argument type of `Function0`. But for the *compiler*, this conversion hasn't taken place yet, thus it tells you `Function0` is not the type required (your before-last try).