# Function that takes parameter of Unit type

Tags: scala

In general, I want to understand how Scala infers the parameter for a function that takes a parameter of Unit type, when `()` is omitted for its invocation.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774516/functions-without-arguments-with-unit-as-argument-in-scala) an example is given:

```
val fun1: Unit => Int = u => 5
```

And it can be invoked in the following way:

```
fun1()
```

How does this compile? Is `()` inferred as the parameter instead of function invocation, i.e. as the inner parentheses as in `fun1(())`?

@[ThaDon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33689/thadon) asked the same question, without an answer being provided.

Further more, I found that this wouldn't work:

```
scala> def unit = ()
scala> fun1 unit
<console>:12: error: value unit is not a member of Unit => Int
   fun1 unit
        ^
```

But this:

```
scala> fun1 ()
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res5: Int = 5
```

and this

```
scala> fun1(unit)
res3: Int = 5
```

both work.

What am I missing with `fun1 unit`? How does the compiler parse this code?

Answer (score 1):

> How does this compile? Is () inferred as the parameter instead of function invocation, i.e. as the inner parentheses as in fun1(())?

Yes. Note the `there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details`. If you do rerun, you'll see the compiler tells you exactly what happens:

```
[warn] /tmp/rendererUa1FraPj2B/src/main/scala/test.scala:7: Adaptation of argument list by inserting () has been deprecated: this is unlikely to be what you want.
[warn]         signature: Function1.apply(v1: T1): R
[warn]   given arguments: <none>
[warn]  after adaptation: Function1((): Unit)
[warn]   fun1()
[warn]       ^
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that inserting `()` for parameters has been deprecated in 2.11.x.

Answer (score 0):

## Function with args needs parenthesis for application in Scala

In order to invoke a function with arguments one has to provide parenthesis after the name of the function.

for Example

```
println("foobar")
```

`fun1(unit)` but not `fun1 unit`

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the deprecation of inserting `()` for parameters in 2.11.x, but I think that's a good change!