# What is the purpose of passing `Unit` to a function in Scala

Tags: scala

Referring to following question in SO, what is the usefulness of passing `Unit` to a function instead of `()` or vice versa?

[Functions without arguments, with unit as argument in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774516/functions-without-arguments-with-unit-as-argument-in-scala)

Comment: I would assume you just stressing the fact that function must have some parameter, even its currently Tuple0 i.e., so you can extend things in the future. Take it as an option to express you original design idea.

Comment: can you edit your question to include some code that shows precisely what you mean to ask? an English phrase like "passing `Unit` to a function" is ambiguous, code is definite.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell you would like to know what is the difference between these two method definitions, and why one would use Unit over () in the function parameter.

```
def func1(f:Unit=>String) = {
  println(f)
}

def func2(f:()=>String) = {
  println(f)
}
```

the difference can be highlighted by looking at the output of this code:

```
func1(Unit => "hello")
func2(() => "hello" )
```

you may be surprised to see this output:

```
<function1>
<function0>
```

Unit=>String is actually a function with 1 parameter.  While ()=>String is a function with 0 parameters.

In Scala () could mean two things

- it could be used for Unit  e.g. val x:Unit = ()
- it can be use to represent no parameters.

In func2, it is a function with no parameters.

"Unit" in func1 is actually the abstract class in the scala package (of which there is only one value "Unit" or "()").  So when the function Unit => String was defined, what we defined was a function that takes a parameter of type Unit as a parameter, and returns a value. Not a Function that takes no parameters.

A final tweak to the code to highlight the difference:

```
def func1(f:Unit=>String) = {
  println(f(Unit))
}

def func2(f:()=>String) = {
  println(f())
  //println(f(Unit)) - does not compile
}


func1(Unit => "hello")
func2(() => "hello" )
```

Will output hello twice.

I'd suggest that func2 or () is generally what people want, and not func1 or "Unit"